# extract a number after and before some string from text using python3

Tags: python, regex, python-3.x

How to extract the string before and after some specific string? and only extract 12 digit numbers for roll no?

```
input_file ="my bday is on 04/01/1997 and 
            frnd bday on 28/12/2018, 
            account no is A000142116 and 
            valid for 30 days for me and 
            for my frnd only 4 DAYS.my roll no is 130302101786
            and register number is 1600523941. Admission number is 
            181212001103" 

for line in input_file:
    m1 = re.findall(r"[\d]{1,2}/[\d]{1,2}/[\d]{4}", line)
    m2 = re.findall(r"A(\d+)", line)
    m3 = re.findall(r"(\d+)days", line)
    m4 = re.findall(r"(\d+)DAYS", line)
    m5 = re.findall(r"(\d+)", line)
    m6 = re.findall(r"(\d+)", line)
    m7 = re.findall(r"(\d+)", line)
    for date_n in m1:
       print(date_n)
    for account_no in m2:
       print(account_no)
    for valid_days in m3:
       print(valid_days)
    for frnd_DAYS in m4:
       print(frnd_DAYS)
    for roll_no in m5:
       print(roll_no)
    for register_no in m6:
       print(register_no)
    for admission_no in m7:
       print(admission_no)
```

Expected Output:

```
04/01/1997
28/12/2018
A000142116
30 days
4 DAYS
130302101786
1600523941
181212001103
```

Answer (score 1):

Use one expression for all of them:

```
\b[A-Z]?\d[/\d]*\b(?:\s+days)?
```

See [**a demo on regex101.com**](https://regex101.com/r/VErMn7/1/).
You'd need to precisize the "account number" format here.

Answer (score 0):

I would use a regex pattern with an alternation for all your possible matches:

```
\d{2}/\d{2}/\d{4}|\d+ days|[A-Z0-9]{10,}
```

This matches either a date, a number of `days`, or an account number.  For account numbers, I assume that there are of length 10 or greater, consisting only of letters and numbers.

```
input_file = """my bday is on 04/01/1997 and 
                frnd bday on 28/12/2018, 
                account no is A000142116 and 
                valid for 30 days for me and 
                for my frnd only 4 DAYS.my roll no is 130302101786
                and register number is 1600523941. Admission number is 
                181212001103"""

results = re.findall(r'\d{2}/\d{2}/\d{4}|\d+ days|[A-Z0-9]{10,}', input_file, flags=re.IGNORECASE)
print(results)

['04/01/1997', '28/12/2018', 'A000142116', '30 days', '4 DAYS', '130302101786',
 '1600523941', '181212001103']
```